# What does the phrase 'I speak the most Italian' mean and what's its structure?

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence-structure, phrase-meaning

After re-watching the Inglorious Bastards for the 100th time, I stumbled upon this phrase said by Pitt's charachter: 'I speak the most Italian'. I understand what the phrase means, but I'm not sure about the structure of it. Is it 'the most Italian' or 'I speak the most' or what? Is there any other examples of usage?

Comment: It depends on the context. Can you post or link to a paragraph or two?

Comment: The scene is as follows: *"LT. ALDO RAINE: "Well, I speak the most Italian, so I'll be your escort. Donowitz speaks the second most, so he'll be your Italian cameraman. And Hirschberg third most, so he'll be Donnys assistant." HIRSCHBERG: "I don't speak Italian." LT. ALDO RAINE: "Like I said, third best. Just keep your fuckin mouth shut. In fact why don't you start practising, right now."*

Answer (score 2):

It is simply "I speak the most Italian (language) (out of this group)", as it might be "I speak more Italian (than he does)".

Comment: Is there an analogy you could think of? Or such phrase is just a single case?

Comment: The context is required to know 'the most compared to whom?', but most comparatives and superlatives work this way; "She has the least money (of the people arguing about the bill)", or "He is the taller (of the brothers)".